# Converting MultiPatch to Point Shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, multipatch

I have a File GeoDatabase that has a Feature Dataset with MultiPatches.  The MultiPatches are tree models.  I would like to convert the MultiPatch into a point layer.

Is there a tool, plugin, or script that will convert the MultiPatch layer into a point feature class?

Comment: Do you have 3D Analyst? If so, an indirect route is use the Multipatch Footprint tool, then find the centroids.

Comment: @mkennedy, good answer...I would like to upvote it as a solution ;)

Comment: Okay, converting to answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have access to the 3D Analyst extension, it's possible to get a two dimensional polygon of the multipatch with the [Multipatch Footprint tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q90000001p000000). From there, you could use the [Feature to Point tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Feature_To_Point/00170000003m000000/) (ArcInfo aka Advanced license) or [Calculate Field tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/#/Calculate_Field/00170000004m000000/) to get the centroids of the polygons.

Comment: Any idea if you can do this without an arcinfo licnese?  I have arc standard.